# AS3 dynamic object properties inside another object

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, object, declaration

I want to create an object with nested objects inside of it whose objects has objects inside of those, like this simple structure:

```
var obj:Object = {
  exercise : {
    question0 : {}
    question1 : {}
    question2 : {}
    question3 : {}
  }
};
```

Then assigning those objects their properties dynamically with the contents of an XML like this:

```
for (var i:uint=0; i<4; i++) {
                    
  obj.exercise["question"+i].original = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].original.@text;
  obj.exercise["question"+i].example = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].example.@text;
  obj.exercise["question"+i].answer = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].answer.@text;
}
```

This code works well; that's the way I know. However the number of `question` objects is dynamic and I'm not able to find a way to define the structure of the main object. So I don't want to have `question0`, `question1`, `question2`, `question3`, `question4`, etc declared from the beginning (without that I get an error).

Just doing this: `var objSenTense:Object = {};` doesn't help either. How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you just have exercise be an array instead of an object?

Comment: This example is just a simplified way of what I really need to do, so I need them to be objects in my complete code. Thanks

Comment: You could just have `{ exercise : { data: ..., otherdata: ..., questions: []} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the creation of the object before editing it:

```
if (!obj.exercise.hasOwnProperty("question"+i))
{
   obj.exercise["question"+i] = {};
}
obj.exercise["question"+i].original = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].original.@text;
obj.exercise["question"+i].example = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].example.@text;
obj.exercise["question"+i].answer = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].answer.@text;
```

Comment: Seems interesting but I don't get it, can you please explain some more? Thanks

Comment: You can leave your `exercise` object empty, the code tests if the object `question?` (where ? is the index) exists in `exercise` and if not it creates it, you won't get any error with that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an array of questions?

```
var obj:Object = {
  exercise : {
    questions:[]
  }
};

for (var i:uint=0; i<4; i++) {

    var question:Object = {};
    question.original = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].original.@text;
    question.example = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].example.@text;
    question.answer = varXML.texts.exercise.question[i].answer.@text;
    obj.exercise.questions.push(question);
}
```

Comment: Surely this works, however the structure of my real code is more complex, so my example was just a representative minimal example. I really need them to be objects. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

To get number of questions from xml, use this code:

```
var length = varXml.texts.exercise.question.length();

for (var i:uint = 0; i < length; i++) { ...
```

Inside the loop you can define as many `question` objects as you want like this:

```
obj.exercise["question"+i] = {};
```

Therefore the initial structure of your `obj` could be as simple as this:

```
var obj = {exercise: {}};
```

Although it would make more sense to use array for questions, not object.

Comment: Thanks I already know it, is a much better way, I have it like that in my real code. However my problem is with the `question0, question1, question2, question3.....` part. Thanks for your help though